# Getting access to records in list of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to create list of `n` arrays and fill only first record in every array with records from `arr` array (first record of first array will be equal to first record from `arr` array, first record of second array will be equal to second record from `arr` array etc.).

In C# it's simple:

```
        List<Point[]> grupy = new List<Point[]>();          //create n array of Point
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            grupy.Add(new Point[10]);                       //array length will be 10

        int a = 0;
        foreach (Point[] x in grupy)                         
        {                                                   
            grupy[a][0] = new Point(arr[a]);                //fill first records in all arrays form list
            a++;
        }
```

But **I need this code in Java** and I noticed that I can't call to records in array from list like that:

```
    List<Point[]> grupy = new ArrayList<Point[]>();     //create n arrays of Point
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            grupy.add(new Point[10]);

    int a = 0;
    for(Point[] x : grupy)                              
    {                                                   
        grupy[a][0] = new Point(arr[a]);         //WRONG WAY
        a++;
    }
```

`grupy.get(a)[0]` dosen't working too. So, my question is: how can I get access to specified record in array from list of arrays?

I know that I can create `temp` array in `for()`, save `arr.get(a)` to `temp[0]` and add `temp` to `grupy` but after i need to display or change specified record and this way won't help.

Comment: you can get from array arr[index] , and from list you can get it l.get(index)

Comment: @bhutto: But grupy.get(index) returns array not a single value from array (grupy it's list of arrays).

Comment: yeah i know, the problem is with arr.get(a) , arr is array data structure.  grupy[a][0] is java list, you dont need to assign list as grupy[a][0], you need to add the element in list as grupy.add(arr[index])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a = 0;
for(Point[] x : grupy)                              
{                                                   
    x[0] = arr[a];
    a++;
}
```

Comment: It helps with save value thanks, but still don't know how to get access to specified record. For example: my `Point` class make avalible to count distance between two point. So i call `double minimum = grupy[0][0].Distance(anotherPoint);` - this method count distance between point from first index from first array form list and another point. But Java don't allow to call `grupy[0][0]`.

Comment: As grupy is a List, you can get a point array using `Point[] mypointArray = grupy.get(0);` . Then simply do `Point myPoint = myPointArray[0];`

Answer (score 0):

If you works with java 8, you can use the Streams API with `forEach`, `map` and `filter` functions